# .NET pass a variable to the second block of code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Very simple question though I'm pretty baffled, I found myself using this function a lot in my controllers so moved it to a method which is my first one. The foreach loop has a final string FinalURL how do I pass that into the httpWebRequest? do I make another method and call it after the break? Before i used a viewbag variable but in this context i cant use it. If i remove the brackets it says not all paths return a function and i believe this isn't the correct way.

```
namespace Linkofy.Models
{
public class MajesticFunctions
{
    public static int[] MajesticChecker(string[] URLtests)
    {
        foreach (string URLt in URLtests)
        {
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URLt);
            myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            int resulting = (int)myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode;
            if (resulting == 200)
            {
                String Urlnew = URLt;
                String FinalURL = URLt.Replace("https://", "").Replace("http://", "");
                break;
            }
        }
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.majestic.com/api/json?app_api_key=KEY&cmd=GetIndexItemInfo&items=1&item0=" + FinalURL + "&datasource=fresh");
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
                JToken Trusty = jObject["DataTables"]["Results"]["Data"][0]["TrustFlow"].Value<int>();
                JToken City = jObject["DataTables"]["Results"]["Data"][0]["CitationFlow"].Value<int>();
                JToken RIPy = jObject["DataTables"]["Results"]["Data"][0]["RefIPs"].Value<int>();

                int Trustflow = Int32.Parse(Trusty.ToString());
                int Citationflow = Int32.Parse(City.ToString());
                int Reffering = Int32.Parse(RIPy.ToString());

                int[] Metrics = new int[] { Trustflow, Citationflow, Reffering };

                return Metrics;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Change the scope of FinalURL and then you can use it directly in HttpWebRequest

Comment: Can you clarify do you expect there to be only a single `FinalURL` coming out of your foreach or do you expect there to be potentially one for each iteration around the loop? As it is I'd expect the latter but your logic looks like you only expect one thing to come out (because you make one request that returns your values. It seems to me like it should be possible for multiple of your `URLtests` items to return status 200 - what do you actually want to happen then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it on the outside of the loop.

That way it will be available in the scope outside of the loop.

```
String FinalURL = "";
foreach (string URLt in URLtests)
        {
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URLt);
            myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            int resulting = (int)myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode;
            if (resulting == 200)
            {
                String Urlnew = URLt;
                FinalURL = URLt.Replace("https://", "").Replace("http://", "");
                break;
            }
        }

if ( FinalURL.Length > 0 )
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.majestic.com/api/json?app_api_key=KEY&cmd=GetIndexItemInfo&items=1&item0=" + FinalURL + "&datasource=fresh");
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
                JToken Trusty = jObject["DataTables"]["Results"]["Data"][0]["TrustFlow"].Value<int>();
                JToken City = jObject["DataTables"]["Results"]["Data"][0]["CitationFlow"].Value<int>();
                JToken RIPy = jObject["DataTables"]["Results"]["Data"][0]["RefIPs"].Value<int>();

                int Trustflow = Int32.Parse(Trusty.ToString());
                int Citationflow = Int32.Parse(City.ToString());
                int Reffering = Int32.Parse(RIPy.ToString());

                int[] Metrics = new int[] { Trustflow, Citationflow, Reffering };

                return Metrics;
            }
        }
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("No Final URL Found");
}
```

Comment: will this still run the if check though? do i keep both iterations?

Comment: What do you mean by both iterations...the finalurl is assigned at most once...and there's only one loop

Comment: sorry if I seem a little dumb to it haha it doesn't make much sense to me. In your example you've taken it outside of the loop. However in my code it only sets the variable if resulting = 200 will this still occur or will it just set it everytime?

Comment: it will only get assigned inside the if block...otherwise it defaults to a blank string

Comment: i gave a more complete example included

Comment: ahh I see! that seems to work for the code block, thanks! However it returns this error now "not all code paths return a value"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163058/discussion-between-ctznkane525-and-liamcook).

Answer (score 0):

You can also move you WebRequest code in for loop

```
namespace Linkofy.Models
{
public class MajesticFunctions
{
    public static int[] MajesticChecker(string[] URLtests)
    {
        foreach (string URLt in URLtests)
        {
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URLt);
            myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            int resulting = (int)myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode;
            if (resulting == 200)
            {

                String FinalURL = URLt.Replace("https://", "").Replace("http://", "");
                if (FinalURL.Length > 0)
                {
                  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.majestic.com/api/json?app_api_key=KEY&cmd=GetIndexItemInfo&items=1&item0=" + FinalURL + "&datasource=fresh");
                  {
                     WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                     using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                     {
                         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                         JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
                         JToken Trusty = jObject["DataTables"]["Results"]["Data"][0]["TrustFlow"].Value<int>();
                         JToken City = jObject["DataTables"]["Results"]["Data"][0]["CitationFlow"].Value<int>();
                         JToken RIPy = jObject["DataTables"]["Results"]["Data"][0]["RefIPs"].Value<int>();

                         int Trustflow = Int32.Parse(Trusty.ToString());
                         int Citationflow = Int32.Parse(City.ToString());
                         int Reffering = Int32.Parse(RIPy.ToString());

                         int[] Metrics = new int[] { Trustflow, Citationflow, Reffering };

                         return Metrics;
                      }
                  }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("No Final URL Found");

       }
}
}
```

Sorry for bad formatting

Comment: thanks for your input I went with the first answer but will defo consider it next time :)